# populate grid with temp table from click event handler d365fo

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365

I am trying to populate a `grid` form with a `temp table` (inMemory) from a click event handler but the `grid` isn't populate. here is my code:

```
class ARQ_CONCCo_InventTransRegisterFormEvents
{

[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(InventTransRegister, ARQImportCSV), FormControlEventType::Clicked)]
public static void ARQImportCSV_OnClicked(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)
{
    TmpInventTransWMS   inventTransWMS, inventTransWMSAux;
    FormDataSource      inventTransWMS_ds;
    FormRun             formRun = sender.formRun() as formRun;

    inventTransWMS_ds = sender.formRun().dataSource(formDataSourceStr(InventTransRegister, TmpInventTransWMS)) as FormDataSource;
    inventTransWMSAux = inventTransWMS_ds.cursor();

    inventTransWMS.InventQty    = 10.00;
    inventTransWMS.UnitId       = "KG";

    inventTransWMS.insert();

    inventTransWMSAux.setTmpData(inventTransWMS);
}

}
```

Comment: Do not forget to refresh the form or form data source after you add data to it. Calling `research()` or `executeQuery()` on your `FormDataSource` object might do the trick.

Comment: @Sander yes I have tried with research(), refresh() and executeQuery() but didn't work

Comment: Your code looks like complete nonsense to me and I would expect it to fail. It looks like you're trying to replace _whatever_ is displayed on a grid with 1 single record? Are you trying to update the selected record? Is multiselect enabled on the grid? Is it always 1 row?

Comment: @Alex Kwitny the grid is empty because its datasource is temp table, I want to populate the grid by code clicking on a button

Comment: @AitorRamosPajares have you just tried after your last line of code adding `inventTransWMS_ds.executeQuery()`? It _should_ work and you should have 1 record in the grid. Have you verified your `inventTransWMS_ds` is correct?